# Add content to sibling div

Tags: javascript

In the example below what's the simplest addContent function that will put some content into the child div?

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:addContent();">My Link</a>
     <div/>
</div>
```

Clicking the link should result in:

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:addContent();">My Link</a>
     <div>Added Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addContent").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next("div").html("<div>Added Content</div>");
    });
});
```

Instead of using an inline function, give your 'add content' links a class, and bind to anchors with that class as in the above example:

```
<a class="addContent" href="#">My Link</a>
```

Try a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/wGz8s/1/